# HTML5 Video Tag currentTime not working in android

Tags: android, html, m3u8, html5-video

I am working with html5 video tag, i am using .m3u8 file for source. I can not able to seek video by using currentTime property in android 4+ whereas if i using .mp4 file i can able to seek.

In ipad its working properly but not working in android. Please guide me to rectify this issue.

Thanks,
Thavaprakash. S.

Answer (score 0):

HLS and Android are not the best of friends.

Some problems I know of are:

- No adaptive bitrate switching: the first quality is picked, no switching will occur.
- When pausing, the video restarts from the beginning (for example with VOD).
- When going fullscreen, the video restarts from the beginning.
- When offering a livestream with DVR, the stream starts at the beginning of the DVR instead of at the "live" moment.
- You cannot seek. <-- this is the one for you
- Aspect ratio's are not detected properly. (tho this should be fixed in 4.1)

On top of these problems, there is no support for HLS in pre 2.3 Android and in 3.0 it actually makes your tablet crash.

Basically: only use HLS on Android for live video without DVR and set the correct aspect ratio. Oh, and try to pick a "suitable" quality, cause it won't switch.

Comment: Hi MrP, Thanks for your response. Sorry for late reply.